# Translating a text document full of numbers into words

Tags: java, string

I'm working on an exercise where I am translating the numbers from a text file into words, the program should show the math behind it in my translate method in my NumberTranslator class, and it should take each individual number from a string of numbers and translate it to its textual value.

For instance, if I have a text file that reads

```
1234

12

34
```

The output would be:

```
1234: One Two Three Four

12: One Two

34: Three Four
```

Here is what I have so far, I believe I have read in the file correctly, but am not sure, and I'm also not sure about my translate() method in my numberTranslator class.

```
package hw05;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

}

public static String readfile(String filename) { //reads the file translate.txt
    String content = null;
    File file = new File("translate.txt");
    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("translate.txt");
        char[] chars = new char[(int) file.length()];
        reader.read(chars);
        content = new String(chars);
        reader.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return content;

}
}
```

And here is my numberTranslator class.

```
package hw05;


public class NumberTranslator extends Main {

private static final String[] words = {"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three",
        "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"};

public String translate(int number){   
    if (number < 10){
        return words[number];
    }
    String result = "";
    while (number >0) {
        if (!"".equals(result)){
            result = "" + result;
        }
        result = words[number % 10] + result;
        number = number / 10;

    } return result;


}

}
```

Comment: Have you run some example files through your code to make sure it behaves correctly?

Comment: I was wondering how to call my NumberTranslator class to actually translate the text file, I'm lost at this point.

Comment: You might want to write some code in your `main` method, otherwise nothing will happen when you run your program.

Comment: Yes I know, how can I call my NumberTranslator class and combine it with my readfile class to read it? Also, David Wallace, are you a boss at Dunder Mifflin? If you have seen the office you'd get the reference:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file and translate it like below:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String line;
int num = 0;
NumberTranslator myAwesomeTranslator = new NumberTranslator();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   try {
      num = Integer.parseInt(line);
      System.out.println(myAwesomeTranslator.translate(num));
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("I thought you were an int :(");
   }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: I'm supposed to show the math behind it, I'm not supposed to use string or characted manipulation to split the number for me, we're supposed to do it ourselves, like the number 123 we take the 3 convert to three and add to final string, take off 2 convert to two add to final string and so on

Comment: oh then you need to use repeated division by 10 and some subtraction to get the digits :)

Comment: How can I test what I have so far? What should I put in my main method?

Comment: Okay, fair enough, using that logic is faster in the first place :)

I don't know why NumberTranslator is extending Main, but you can instantiate NumberTranslator and do like myTranslator.translate(Integer.parseInt(line)); assuming line is int-parsable.

Comment: Can you explain that last part of code, and int-parsable? I don't quite understand it, sorry.

Comment: Just check whether it's a proper int or not, so you could call your translate() method. See edit.

Comment: Alright, it seems like that is working, but now I'm getting this as an output,

Six
I thought you were an int :(

I thought you were an int :(

I thought you were an int :(
So that means those are exceptions? How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to output the line String first, check if it is numeric, for example, check whether it has trailing or leading whitespaces (in that case use String.trim(line)). Check your code AND your FILE :)

Comment: where would I put String.trim(line); ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48633/discussion-between-kuma-and-tonno22)

Comment: I've changed it to System.out.println(line + ": " + myAwesomeTranslator.translate(num));

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public String translate(int number){  
    String numberString = Integer.toString(number);
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numberString.length(); i++) {
        char letter = numberString.charAt(i);
        result += words[Integer.parseInt(letter)] + " ";
    } 
    return result;
```

I haven't tested it but you should get the idea, and you'll like have to add some Exception handling.

Comment: You said you suspected there is. I wanted to show you what I think is a simpler option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it :

1. Create an array that has the numbers written in words from zero to nine.
2. Start reading the file using `BufferedReader`.
3. For each line obtained as `String`, obtain the `length()` and start iterating from 0 to that `length - 1`. use `charAt()` to get the number.
4. Parse it to an integer using `Integer.parseInt()`
5. Index your array to obtain the translation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Map,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
    {
        Map<Integer, String> wordMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        wordMap.put(0, "Zero");
        wordMap.put(1, "One");
        wordMap.put(2, "Two");
        wordMap.put(3, "Three");
        wordMap.put(4, "Four");
        wordMap.put(5, "Five");
        wordMap.put(6, "Six");
        wordMap.put(7, "Seven");
        wordMap.put(8, "Eight");
        wordMap.put(9, "Nine");

        String fileName = "location\file";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(fileName)));

        String content = null;
        while((content = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            for(char number : content.toCharArray())
            {
                System.out.print(wordMap.get(Character.getNumericValue(number))); //write into another file
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Map is an overkill here. Not needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

For text replacement the regular expressions are very useful:

```
private static final String[] words = {" Zero", " One", " Two", " Three",
            " Four", " Five", " Six", " Seven", " Eight", " Nine"};


....

String text = _obtain your text string here_;

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            text = text.replaceAll(String.valueOf(i), words[i]);
}
```

Pay attention: in array there are whitespaces already before each word name.